# Using GUI with JLink

Tags: java

How to handle Input/Manipulate expressions using JLink? Say I want to handle the $Input[]$ expression sent via JLink to the MathKernel. Currently the my app blocks on waiting the response.

How this kind of requests are handled by MathKernel?